# unable to create a file in another partition of disk in manjaro

Tags: manjaro, dolphin

I am new with Manjaro and I am really enjoying it and I have a dual boot system(Window-10 + Manjaro). In starting everything working fine but since when I boot the window and after that I am not able to create any file in other portions of the disk and I am login to Manjaro as administrator for more info please check the attached image. when I right-click for creating a new file what i find the option is disable. how I can fix this?  [image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create a file/folder on a Windows 10 partition? Look up "Windows Fast boot" with regard to Linux.

Comment: No in different partition

Comment: "Fast boot" may also affect other partitions than your Windows partition. Try to shut down your Windows holding the shift key and test if your partition is writable after that.

Comment: you are perfactly right now it's working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I was having the same problem and this is what worked for me:

Do you plan on doing read/write on your Windows partition?

Disable Windows options like

1. Fast Startup
2. Hybrid Sleep

Windows Hybrid Sleep defaults to enabled on desktop computers and disabled for laptop computers.

Why should I do that? When Windows uses the above options it leaves the file system in a dirty state. When the file system is in this state the Linux filesystem tool ntfs-3g mounts the file system read-only, effectively blocking you from making changes to your files on the Windows partition.

To disable Windows Fast Startup you need to access the Windows Control Panel.

You find it by clicking on Windows Start button → type control → select Control Panel desktop app.

In the Control Panel app:

1. Click on System and Security
2. Click on Power Options
3. Click on Choose what power buttons do
4. Click on Change settings that are currently unavailable
5. Uncheck the option Turn on fast startup
6. Click on Save Changes

Hope it helps.

source: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-dual-boot-manjaro-windows-10-step-by-step/52668